# Oracle nls_sort equivalent in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, collation, nls-sort, nls-comp

Working in migration of DB from Oracle to Postgres. I'm trying to achieve the sorting behavior in my application, where alphanumeric label starting with digits need to come after letters (explained in below example).

I tried the french collation in Postgres, but couldn't achieve the same result which I got in Oracle using `NLS_SORT "french"`.

Posting Oracle queries, I need an equivalent in Postgres which can be set in DB once so that application uses it afterwards.

**Oracle:**

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='FRENCH';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
select LABEL from CARBON order by LABEL ;

 LABEL
    APPLE
    BALL
    102C
    108C
    108D
```

**Postgres:**

I tried by  creating collation named `french` from the `pg_collation` entry `fr-FR-x-icu` and alter the existing table column using the pgAdmin GUI like this:

```
label character varying(255) COLLATE public.french NOT NULL
```

No luck, I am getting the same result.

```
select LABEL from CARBON order by LABEL ;

LABEL
102C
108C
108D
APPLE
BALL
```

I tried the below query also in Postgres , it is giving the same result as above. Am I missing something in Postgres?

```
select LABEL from CARBON order by LABEL collate "fr_FR"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve that by creating a custom ICU collation (available from PostgreSQL v10 on) that sorts digits greater than Latin characters:

```
CREATE COLLATION weird (
   LOCALE = 'fr-u-kr-latn-digit',
   PROVIDER = 'icu'
);

ALTER TABLE carbon ALTER label TYPE text COLLATE weird;

SELECT * FROM carbon ORDER BY label COLLATE weird;

 label 
-------
 APPLE
 BALL
 102C
 108C
 108D
(5 rows)
```

This assumes a recent ICU library, old versions have a somewhat different syntax.

With older versions of the ICU library, you may have to use

```
CREATE COLLATION digitslast (
   PROVIDER = 'icu',
   LOCALE = 'fr@colReorder=latn-digit'
);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this vith PG 12.2 on CentOS 7.7: collation is created but the order does not change. Same result if I use `CREATE COLLATION digitslast (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colReorder=latn-digit');`. Why ?

Comment: Don't know; I don't have CentOS 7 available. What is the version of the ICU library?

Comment: Both my and your syntax work on my Fedora System with libicu 63.2.

Comment: We had this previously that the ICU library shipped with CentOS (and Windows) is pretty outdated. The solutions for case-insensitive collations also needed some tweaking. [Your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255783/1822) was to use a different ICU "definition". Maybe that is needed here as well

Comment: This works with PG 10.12 on Ubuntu 18 which is using iculib 60. Currently I cannot make PG 12.2 to use iculib 63.2 on Centos 7.7 if PG is installed with yum (looks like ldd says that PG 12.2 has hardcoded iculib 50.2 in /lib64.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, that's the version that pifor suggested (and that works for me).

Comment: I managed to get this working with PG 12.2 on CentOS 7.7 with libicu 63.2: it is needed to install libicu 63.2 from source code (found no RPM) with `./configure --target=Linux --libdir=/lib64` and rebuilding PG 12.2 from source with additional `--with-icu` flag for PG `./configure` step. Building libicu takes almost the same time than building PG.

Comment: libicu 63.2 link=https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-63-2/icu4c-63_2-src.tgz

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , i tried in windows Postgres 11 version , i couldn't find icu version for my postgres. tried both old and new syntax its not working . Then created db from template0 with collate and ctype as French_france , then tried same old and new collation .. its not working in windows.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , i also tried one more thing like mentioned in https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/requirements-nlscomp-and-nlssort-oracle-database-settings-process-engine , oracle jdbc driver honouring the language, country , region parameters set as JVM arguments and setting NLS_LANG to that settings for DB connections. But postgres jdbc is not honouring those arguments.

Comment: Oh, Windows. Well, it depends if your PostgreSQL was built with ICU support or not. If not you are out of luck. What do you get for `SELECT count(*) FROM pg_collation WHERE collprovider = 'i';`? If anything greater than 0, you have ICU support. If not, you could try building PostgreSQL from source with ICU support.